# Drop nonconsecutive values (Stata or R)

Tags: r, stata

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), month = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13), dummy = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-29L))
```

Grouping by id, I wish to keep consecutive runs of the dummy variable equaling 1 if the run is greater than or equal to 3.

For example, if for a given id, I have only two consecutive 1's followed by a 0, I want to drop these three rows.

In the end I wish to keep only "ones" (consecutive, in a run greater than 2).

If the answer is for Stata, I need to do it without any program/package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using run length encoding (rle) you could try one of the following.

With `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[,
          my_length := with(rle(dummy), rep(lengths * values, lengths)),
          by = id][my_length > 2]
```

With `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr) # v1.1.0

filter(df, rep(rle(dummy)$values == 1 & rle(dummy)$lengths > 2, 
               rle(dummy)$lengths), 
       .by = id)
```

**Output**

```
      id month dummy
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     2     3     1
 2     2     4     1
 3     2     5     1
 4     3    13     1
 5     3    14     1
 6     3    15     1
 7     3    16     1
 8     3    17     1
 9     4     5     1
10     4     6     1
11     4     7     1
12     4    10     1
13     4    11     1
14     4    12     1
15     4    13     1
```

Answer (score 2):

With `dplyr` version >= 1.1.0, we can use `consecutive_id` to group blocks of identical values, and we can `group_by` the `conseuctive_id` and `id` columns, then `filter` for any group that has more than two observation and with `dummy` equals 1.

Replace `consecutive_id()` with `data.table::rleid()` if your `dplyr` version is older than 1.1.0.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(id, id2 = consecutive_id(dummy)) %>% 
  filter(dummy == 1 & n() > 2) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-id2)

# A tibble: 15 × 3
      id month dummy
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     2     3     1
 2     2     4     1
 3     2     5     1
 4     3    13     1
 5     3    14     1
 6     3    15     1
 7     3    16     1
 8     3    17     1
 9     4     5     1
10     4     6     1
11     4     7     1
12     4    10     1
13     4    11     1
14     4    12     1
15     4    13     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the Stata example! (R people here would be a little irritated if you had given that ....)

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input float(dummy month id)
1  1 1
0  2 1
0  3 1
0  4 1
0  5 1
0  6 1
1  3 2
1  4 2
1  5 2
1 10 3
1 11 3
0 12 3
1 13 3
1 14 3
1 15 3
1 16 3
1 17 3
1  2 4
1  3 4
0  4 4
1  5 4
1  6 4
1  7 4
0  8 4
0  9 4
1 10 4
1 11 4
1 12 4
1 13 4
end 

gen seq = _n
bysort id (seq) : gen run = cond(dummy == 0, ., sum(dummy == 1 & dummy[_n-1] != 1))  
bysort id run: keep if dummy & _N > 2 

list, sepby(id run)

     +--------------------------------+
     | dummy   month   id   seq   run |
     |--------------------------------|
  1. |     1       3    2     7     1 |
  2. |     1       4    2     8     1 |
  3. |     1       5    2     9     1 |
     |--------------------------------|
  4. |     1      13    3    13     2 |
  5. |     1      14    3    14     2 |
  6. |     1      15    3    15     2 |
  7. |     1      16    3    16     2 |
  8. |     1      17    3    17     2 |
     |--------------------------------|
  9. |     1       5    4    21     2 |
 10. |     1       6    4    22     2 |
 11. |     1       7    4    23     2 |
     |--------------------------------|
 12. |     1      10    4    26     3 |
 13. |     1      11    4    27     3 |
 14. |     1      12    4    28     3 |
 15. |     1      13    4    29     3 |
     +--------------------------------+
```

This is a solution if `tsspell` from SSC were allowed, which is longer, but in practice with data of this kind a sequence variable might already exist and the dataset also be `tsset` already.

```
gen seq = _n
tsset id seq 
tsspell, cond(dummy==1)
bysort id _spell (seq) : keep if dummy &  _N > 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a solution in R using dplyr, using `cumsum()` with `lag()` to identify runs, then filtering to runs of `1` with 3 or more rows.

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  group_by(id, run_grp = cumsum(dummy != lag(dummy, default = -1))) %>%
  filter(n() >= 3, dummy == 1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(!run_grp)
```

```
# A tibble: 15 × 3
      id month dummy
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     2     3     1
 2     2     4     1
 3     2     5     1
 4     3    13     1
 5     3    14     1
 6     3    15     1
 7     3    16     1
 8     3    17     1
 9     4     5     1
10     4     6     1
11     4     7     1
12     4    10     1
13     4    11     1
14     4    12     1
15     4    13     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another data.table Solution:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,N := .N,.(rleid(dummy),id)][N>2&dummy]

    id month dummy N
 1:  2     3     1 3
 2:  2     4     1 3
 3:  2     5     1 3
 4:  3    13     1 5
 5:  3    14     1 5
 6:  3    15     1 5
 7:  3    16     1 5
 8:  3    17     1 5
 9:  4     5     1 3
10:  4     6     1 3
11:  4     7     1 3
12:  4    10     1 4
13:  4    11     1 4
14:  4    12     1 4
15:  4    13     1 4
```

in base R:

```
subset(df, dummy & ave(dummy, id, 
     FUN = \(x)ave(x, cumsum(c(1, !!diff(x))), FUN=length)) > 2)

   id month dummy
7   2     3     1
8   2     4     1
9   2     5     1
13  3    13     1
14  3    14     1
15  3    15     1
16  3    16     1
17  3    17     1
21  4     5     1
22  4     6     1
23  4     7     1
26  4    10     1
27  4    11     1
28  4    12     1
29  4    13     1
```